# Validation to prevent parent referencing self as children

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking for a solution to prevent "parents" to add his self as "children".

My Model looks like this:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Category'
  has_many :children, :class_name => 'Category', :foreign_key => 'parent_id'
end
```

Now I look for a solution to prevent things like this

```
parent = Category.create(name: "Parent")
Category.new(name: "Children", parent_id: parent.id).valid? # should be => false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a [custom validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations) for that.

Something like

```
class ParentValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    if record.parent_id == record.id
      record.errors[:parent_id] << 'A record\'s parent cannot be the record itself'
    end
  end
end

class Category
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  validates_with ParentValidator
end
```

or even simpler (if it is a one off thing)

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :parent_not_self, on: :save

  def parent_not_self
    if parent_id == id
      errors.add(:parent_id, 'A record\'s parent cannot be the record itself')
    end
  end
end
```

Both cases will generate a validation error when you try to assign the record itself as the parent's record